# pd-for-android, pdtest, Can't create externals

Tags: android, puredata, libpd

After recent update to libpd , can't seem to load externals.

https://github.com/libpd/pd-for-android/issues/127

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding a flag in the manifest file under the `<application>` tag:

```
android:extractNativeLibs="true"
```